# Apache HttpClient 5.0 HTTPS proxy: "No tunnel unless connected"

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am using the latest version of JDK8
My `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` is created by doing the following

```
        try{
            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .setProvider(Conscrypt.newProvider())
                    .build();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setTlsStrategy(new ConscryptClientTlsStrategy(sslContext))
                .build();

BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            if (proxy.isAuth()) {
                credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(proxy.getIp(), Integer.parseInt(proxy.getPort())),
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxy.getUsername(), proxy.getPassword().toCharArray()));
            }

HttpHost p = new HttpHost(proxy.getIp(), Integer.parseInt(proxy.getPort()), "http");

asyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                    .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_1)
                    .setConnectionManager(cm)
                    .setUserAgent(Utils.USER_AGENT)
                    .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setProxy(p)
                    .build();

asyncClient.start();
```

I am then trying to do a post request which works without a proxy. The request with the proxy also works with the url using http and not https. I receive the following error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tunnel unless connected` when using https and a proxy.

Comment: Please raise a JIRA with the project and ideally provide a test app that can be used to reproduce the defect.